# asp.net ListView properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have an asp:listView which displays some IEnumerable objects supplied by a stored procedure from the DB.

How is it possible to delete each entry with the help of a button? i.e: if you click on a row you get the option to delete it.

In the options, Editing, Inserting, Deleting are grayed out and cannot be selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think they might be grayed out because you are not directly connection the listview to the database.
You should be able to get the selected item (or items) from the listview and if they have some sort of ID field stored in a property you can delete it from the object supplier, call delete to the database and then delete it from the listview.

Comment: Yes they do have an ID which matches the ID in the DB table but how do I go about enabling to select a row (i.e: clicking on it to select it)? I also have a separate Delete stored procedure which can delete an entry based on supplying the ID

Comment: You cant select the row? is the ListView enabled?

Comment: Yes because it is being displayed, its just not clickable, its just text.